# Discrete vs Continuous Dynamics

Tags: soft-question, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Where does the problem arise concretely in considering a discrete process as a sampling of a continuous process? Can we use continuous methods of solving say differential equations and find the solution of a discrete system by taking the solution only at the distinct integral values?

If it doesn't not fail concretely, why does it fail abstractly?

Comment: Can you give an example of where it fails abstractly ? Or explain what you mean by that statement

Comment: It may fail because there are some examples of discrete processes (I mean diffeomorphisms and dynamic of its iterations) that can't be embedded in continuous process (here I mean flows on manifolds). Some simple example: map $f(x, y) = (-\frac{1}{2}x, \frac{1}{2}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can't be embedded into the flow. Such maps easily occur in discrete processes (locally, for example), so this is typically "intractable" in terms of the flow.

Comment: I meant $f(x, y) = (-\frac{1}{2} x , \frac{1}{2} y )$